# SQL Server CTE query duplicated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

My table is as follows:

```
ID      Name     Parent
1       Joe         -
2       James       -
3       Mike        1
4       Lewis       3
5       Anne        2
6       Lucy        4
```

The output is the expected one but I'm having all values duplicated with this query:

```
with cte as (
  select name
  from Materials
  where name= 'Joe'
  union all
  select Materials.name
  from cte join
       Materials
       on Materials.parent = cte.id
)
select name, id
from cte;
```

Output:

```
Joe
Joe
Mike
Lewis
Lucy
Mike
Lewis
Lucy
```

Any idea about what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data DOES NOT product duplicates.  See this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=afbc78b11d9d137a327602d153652cf5).

A simple solution is to use `select distinct`:

```
with cte as (
      select m.name
      from Materials m
      where m.name = 'Joe'
      union all
      select m.name
      from cte join
           Materials m
           on Materials.parent = cte.id
    )
select distinct name
from cte;
```

Comment: Maybe it's because I simplified the database because I thought that it would be clearer and the results would be similar.